# Object Has Additional Attribute ActionContext etc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-web-api

Hi I have Web API Project in ASP.net MVC (not Core) I have simple class let me show you;

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace WebAPI
{
    public class TumKartlar : ApiController
    {
        public string AD { get; set; }
        public string SOYAD { get; set; }
        public string KARTID { get; set; }
        public string OGRNO { get; set; }
        public string TCKIMLIK { get; set; }
        public string AKKTAR { get; set; }

        public int Durum { get; set; }
        public string DurumMesaji { get; set; }
    }
}
```

as you see all my attribute are these. But when i run get method my response is; (I guess problem is my filter class. Bu i don't know how can i fix this. There are lot of unnecessary information, how can i filter them? )

```
{
"AD": "Muhammed",
"SOYAD": "xxxxx",
"KARTID": "44444",
"OGRNO": "xxxxx",
"TCKIMLIK": "xxxxxx",
"AKKTAR": "12/16/2019 2:33:00 PM",
"Durum": 1,
"DurumMesaji": "Kişi Bilgisi Bulundu",
"Configuration": null,
"ControllerContext": {
    "Configuration": null,
    "ControllerDescriptor": null,
    "Controller": null,
    "Request": null,
    "RequestContext": {
        "Request": null,
        "ClientCertificate": null,
        "Configuration": null,
        "IncludeErrorDetail": false,
        "IsLocal": false,
        "RouteData": null,
        "Url": null,
        "VirtualPathRoot": null,
        "Principal": {
            "m_identity": {
                "m_name": "",
                "m_type": "",
                "m_version": "1.0",
                "m_actor": null,
                "m_authenticationType": null,
                "m_bootstrapContext": null,
                "m_label": null,
                "m_serializedNameType": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name",
                "m_serializedRoleType": "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role",
                "m_serializedClaims": "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"
            },
            "m_roles": [],
            "m_version": "1.0",
            "m_serializedClaimsIdentities": "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"
        }
    },
    "RouteData": null
},
"ActionContext": {
    "ControllerContext": {
        "Configuration": null,
        "ControllerDescriptor": null,
        "Controller": null,
        "Request": null,
        "RequestContext": {
            "Request": null,
            "ClientCertificate": null,
            "Configuration": null,
            "IncludeErrorDetail": false,
            "IsLocal": false,
            "RouteData": null,
            "Url": null,
            "VirtualPathRoot": null,
            "Principal": {
                "m_identity": {
                    "m_name": "",
                    "m_type": "",
                    "m_version": "1.0",
                    "m_actor": null,
                    "m_authenticationType": null,
                    "m_bootstrapContext": null,
                    "m_label": null,
                    "m_serializedNameType": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name",
                    "m_serializedRoleType": "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role",
                    "m_serializedClaims": "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"
                },
                "m_roles": [],
                "m_version": "1.0",
                "m_serializedClaimsIdentities": "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"
            }
        },
        "RouteData": null
    },
    "ActionDescriptor": null,
    "ModelState": {},
    "ActionArguments": {},
    "Response": null,
    "Request": null,
    "RequestContext": {
        "Request": null,
        "ClientCertificate": null,
        "Configuration": null,
        "IncludeErrorDetail": false,
        "IsLocal": false,
        "RouteData": null,
        "Url": null,
        "VirtualPathRoot": null,
        "Principal": {
            "m_identity": {
                "m_name": "",
                "m_type": "",
                "m_version": "1.0",
                "m_actor": null,
                "m_authenticationType": null,
                "m_bootstrapContext": null,
                "m_label": null,
                "m_serializedNameType": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name",
                "m_serializedRoleType": "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role",
                "m_serializedClaims": "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"
            },
            "m_roles": [],
            "m_version": "1.0",
            "m_serializedClaimsIdentities": "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"
        }
    }
},
"ModelState": {},
"Request": null,
"RequestContext": {
    "Request": null,
    "ClientCertificate": null,
    "Configuration": null,
    "IncludeErrorDetail": false,
    "IsLocal": false,
    "RouteData": null,
    "Url": null,
    "VirtualPathRoot": null,
    "Principal": {
        "m_identity": {
            "m_name": "",
            "m_type": "",
            "m_version": "1.0",
            "m_actor": null,
            "m_authenticationType": null,
            "m_bootstrapContext": null,
            "m_label": null,
            "m_serializedNameType": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name",
            "m_serializedRoleType": "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role",
            "m_serializedClaims": "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"
        },
        "m_roles": [],
        "m_version": "1.0",
        "m_serializedClaimsIdentities": "AAEAAAD/////AQAAAAAAAAAEAQAAAH9TeXN0ZW0uQ29sbGVjdGlvbnMuR2VuZXJpYy5MaXN0YDFbW1N5c3RlbS5TdHJpbmcsIG1zY29ybGliLCBWZXJzaW9uPTQuMC4wLjAsIEN1bHR1cmU9bmV1dHJhbCwgUHVibGljS2V5VG9rZW49Yjc3YTVjNTYxOTM0ZTA4OV1dAwAAAAZfaXRlbXMFX3NpemUIX3ZlcnNpb24GAAAICAkCAAAAAgAAAAIAAAARAgAAAAQAAAAGAwAAAAAGBAAAALAQQUFFQUFBRC8vLy8vQVFBQUFBQUFBQUFFQVFBQUFDbFRlWE4wWlcwdVUyVmpkWEpwZEhrdVVISnBibU5wY0dGc0xrZGxibVZ5YVdOSlpHVnVkR2wwZVFvQUFBQUdiVjl1WVcxbEJtMWZkSGx3WlJoRGJHRnBiWE5KWkdWdWRHbDBlU3R0WDNabGNuTnBiMjRXUTJ4aGFXMXpTV1JsYm5ScGRIa3JiVjloWTNSdmNpTkRiR0ZwYlhOSlpHVnVkR2wwZVN0dFgyRjFkR2hsYm5ScFkyRjBhVzl1Vkhsd1pTRkRiR0ZwYlhOSlpHVnVkR2wwZVN0dFgySnZiM1J6ZEhKaGNFTnZiblJsZUhRV1EyeGhhVzF6U1dSbGJuUnBkSGtyYlY5c1lXSmxiQ05EYkdGcGJYTkpaR1Z1ZEdsMGVTdHRYM05sY21saGJHbDZaV1JPWVcxbFZIbHdaU05EYkdGcGJYTkpaR1Z1ZEdsMGVTdHRYM05sY21saGJHbDZaV1JTYjJ4bFZIbHdaU0ZEYkdGcGJYTkpaR1Z1ZEdsMGVTdHRYM05sY21saGJHbDZaV1JEYkdGcGJYTUJBUUVEQVFJQkFRRUJKVk41YzNSbGJTNVRaV04xY21sMGVTNURiR0ZwYlhNdVEyeGhhVzF6U1dSbGJuUnBkSGtHQWdBQUFBQUpBZ0FBQUFZREFBQUFBekV1TUFvS0Nnb0dCQUFBQURwb2RIUndPaTh2YzJOb1pXMWhjeTU0Yld4emIyRndMbTl5Wnk5M2N5OHlNREExTHpBMUwybGtaVzUwYVhSNUwyTnNZV2x0Y3k5dVlXMWxCZ1VBQUFBOGFIUjBjRG92TDNOamFHVnRZWE11YldsamNtOXpiMlowTG1OdmJTOTNjeTh5TURBNEx6QTJMMmxrWlc1MGFYUjVMMk5zWVdsdGN5OXliMnhsQmdZQUFBQ0lDRUZCUlVGQlFVUXZMeTh2TDBGUlFVRkJRVUZCUVVGQlJVRlJRVUZCU1RSQ1ZUTnNlbVJIVm5STWEwNTJZa2Q0YkZrelVuQmlNalY2VEd0a2JHSnRWbmxoVjAxMVZFZHNlbVJIUVhoWE1YUlVaVmhPTUZwWE1IVlZNbFpxWkZoS2NHUklhM1ZSTW5ob1lWY3hla3hyVG5OWlYyeDBURU5DZEdNeVRuWmpiWGh3V1dsM1oxWnRWbmxqTW14Mlltb3dNRXhxUVhWTlF6UjNURU5DUkdSWGVEQmtXRXBzVUZjMWJHUllVbmxaVjNkelNVWkNNVmx0ZUhCWk1IUnNaVlpTZG1FeVZuVlFWMGt6VGpKRk1WbDZWVEpOVkd0NlRrZFZkMDlFYkdSWVVVMUJRVUZCUjFneWJEQmFWekY2UWxZNWVtRlljR3hEUmpreVdsaEtlbUZYT1hWQmQwRkJTR3hPTldNelVteGlVelZVV2xkT01XTnRiREJsVXpWRVlrZEdjR0pZVFhWUk1uaG9ZVmN4WWxoUlowbERVVWxCUVVGQlFrRkJRVUZCVVVGQlFVRmpRMEZCUVVGQlFVVkJRVUZCUlVGQlFVRkJlSGhVWlZoT01GcFhNSFZWTWxacVpGaEtjR1JJYTNWUk1uaG9ZVmN4ZWt4clRuTlpWMngwUTFGTlFVRkJRVTVCZDFGRVFVRkJRVWhHVGpWak0xSnNZbE0xVkZwWFRqRmpiV3d3WlZNMVJHSkhSbkJpV0UxMVVUSjRhR0ZYTUVkQlFVRkJRMGN4Wm1GWVRucGtWMVo1UlVjeFptSXpTbkJhTW14MVdWZDRTbU16VGpGYVdFbEhZbFk1TUdWWVFteENNakZtWkcxR2MyUlhWVXhpVmpreVdWZDRNVnBXVWpWalIxVk5ZbFk1ZDJOdE9YZGFXRW93WVZkV2VrRlJSVUpCVVVWRU5HZEdWR1ZZVGpCYVZ6QjFVVEk1YzJKSFZtcGtSMngyWW01TmRWSXlWblZhV0Vwd1dYazFSV0ZYVGpCaFZ6bDFXVmhLTlZsRVNtSlhNVTQxWXpOU2JHSlROVlJrU0Vwd1ltMWpjMGxITVhwWk1qbDVZa2RzYVV4RFFsZGFXRXA2WVZjNWRWQlVVWFZOUXpSM1RHcEJjMGxGVGpGaVNGSXhZMjFWT1dKdFZqRmtTRXBvWWtOM1oxVklWbWxpUjJ4cVV6SldOVlpIT1hKYVZ6UTVXV3BqTTFsVVZtcE9WRmw0VDFSTk1GcFVRVFJQVmpCelZ6Rk9OV016VW14aVV6VlVaRWhLY0dKdFkzTkpSekY2V1RJNWVXSkhiR2xNUTBKWFdsaEtlbUZYT1hWUVZGRjFUVU0wZDB4cVFYTkpSVTR4WWtoU01XTnRWVGxpYlZZeFpFaEthR0pEZDJkVlNGWnBZa2RzYWxNeVZqVldSemx5V2xjME9WbHFZek5aVkZacVRsUlplRTlVVFRCYVZFRTBUMVl4WkVKblVVRkJRVUZRVkVVNVJGRlZkMmRSVmxaVlUwVTVVMU5XVWxwRFVWRkJRVUZCUjBKUlFVRkJSSEJ2WkVoU2QwOXBPSFpqTWs1dldsY3hhR041TlRSaVYzaDZZakpHZDB4dE9YbGFlVGt6WTNrNGVVMUVRVEZNZWtFeFRESnNhMXBYTlRCaFdGSTFUREpPYzFsWGJIUmplVGwxV1ZjeGJFSm5XVUZCUVVGQlFtZGpRVUZCUVc1aFNGSXdZMFJ2ZGt3elpETmtlVFV6VFhrMWRtTnRZM1pOYWtGM1RWTTVXVlJWZUZSWk1taHNZbGRGYW1NelVubGhWelZ1UTJkelBRcz0NAgs="
    }
},
"Url": null,
"User": {
    "m_identity": {
        "m_name": "",
        "m_type": "",
        "m_version": "1.0",
        "m_actor": null,
        "m_authenticationType": null,
        "m_bootstrapContext": null,
        "m_label": null,
        "m_serializedNameType": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name",
        "m_serializedRoleType": "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role",
        "m_serializedClaims": "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"
    },
    "m_roles": [],
    "m_version": "1.0",
    "m_serializedClaimsIdentities": "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"
}
```

}

what all of there stuffs, can u explain why are these here? I just want to return my object attributes, not these stuffss

Answer (score 0):

Your object inherits from `ApiController`:

```
public class TumKartlar : ApiController
```

And those are properties of an `ApiController`.  I guess the most immediate solution would be to not inherit from that class if you don't want your object to be an instance of that class:

```
public class TumKartlar
{
    // your object members
}
```